# tab.setIcon(resId) not working after project upgraded in MDC Android

Tags: android, icons, android-tablayout, material-components-android, android-vectordrawable

I have recently upgraded my project in Google Material Designing Component. I have used tab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_test_icon) to set the icon. Now below icon is not working. but, working file before upgrade. Have e shared drawable xml.

ic_test_icon.xml

```xml
    <vector android:alpha="0.64" android:height="18dp"
    android:viewportHeight="18" android:viewportWidth="17"
    android:width="17dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M1,0L16,0A1,1 0,0 1,17 1L17,17A1,1 0,0 1,16 18L1,18A1,1 0,0 1,0 17L0,1A1,1 0,0 1,1 0z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#6f6f6f" android:pathData="M14.283,12.908v-8.7a0.743,0.743 0,0 0,-0.742 -0.742h-10.8a0.743,0.743 0,0 0,-0.742 0.742v8.7a0.743,0.743 0,0 0,0.742 0.742h10.8A0.743,0.743 0,0 0,14.283 12.908ZM2.631,12.908v-3.4l1.684,-1.684a0.106,0.106 0,0 1,0.15 0l0.362,0.362a0.318,0.318 0,1 0,0.45 -0.45l-0.362,-0.362a0.742,0.742 0,0 0,-1.049 0l-1.234,1.234L2.632,4.204a0.106,0.106 0,0 1,0.106 -0.106h10.8a0.106,0.106 0,0 1,0.106 0.106v8.7a0.106,0.106 0,0 1,-0.106 0.106h-0.31l-3.962,-3.962a0.743,0.743 0,0 0,-1.049 0l-0.815,0.815L6.289,8.752a0.318,0.318 0,0 0,-0.45 0.45l1.19,1.19a0.53,0.53 0,0 0,0.75 0l0.89,-0.89a0.106,0.106 0,0 1,0.15 0l3.512,3.512L2.737,13.014A0.106,0.106 0,0 1,2.631 12.908Z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#6f6f6f" android:pathData="M2.7589,15.1412m-0.0441,0.4428a0.445,0.445 50.682,1 1,0.0881 -0.8856a0.445,0.445 50.682,1 1,-0.0881 0.8856"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#6f6f6f" android:pathData="M4.3339,15.1412m-0.0441,0.4428a0.445,0.445 50.682,1 1,0.0881 -0.8856a0.445,0.445 50.682,1 1,-0.0881 0.8856"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#6f6f6f" android:pathData="M5.9089,15.1412m-0.0441,0.4428a0.445,0.445 50.682,1 1,0.0881 -0.8856a0.445,0.445 50.682,1 1,-0.0881 0.8856"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#6f6f6f" android:pathData="M9.362,2.435a0.318,0.318 0,0 0,0 -0.636h-1.378a0.318,0.318 0,0 0,0 0.636Z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#6f6f6f" android:pathData="M6.353,2.435a0.318,0.318 0,0 0,0 -0.636h-3.763a0.318,0.318 0,1 0,0 0.636Z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#6f6f6f" android:pathData="M10.833,7.922A1.126,1.126 0,1 0,9.702 6.794,1.128 1.128,0 0,0 10.833,7.922ZM10.833,6.306a0.49,0.49 0,1 1,-0.49 0.49A0.491,0.491 0,0 1,10.833 6.306Z"/>
</vector>
```

Except this all icons are working fine.

Need help to find out this issue.

TIA

[image: Tab items icon]

Comment: which version of MDC?

Comment: I have implement "com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0"